# Local volatility grids - Monte carlo - Implementation

Tags: monte-carlo, local-volatility

I read the paper "Monte Carlo pricing with local volatility grids" (authors: D.F. Abasto, B. Hientzsch and M.P. Kust) and I would like to know if anyone on this forum had a chance to implement it as I have practical questions related its concrete implementation. Could you please explain me what difference exists between the original paper from Andreasen-Huge and this paper? And what would be the impact in terms of implementation (optimization approach)? Many thanks.

Comment: Just ask your question, this seems on-topic.